# MPDF Try to keep div on same page

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am developing a web application in PHP that needs to generate some invoices, and I chose mpdf to do this.

Now, I have the following challenge: the invoice exists out some divs under eachother. I want MPDF to try and see if this FULL div fits on 1 page. If this is the only div on the page, it can overflow to the next page. If it's the second or third, fourth, etc. then this whole div needs to be put on the next page.

I tried this "avoid page break"  but it bugs a lot and creates empty pages.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: How about to add a new page for each invoice?

Comment: There is just one invoice, it exists of multiple divs. Some divs are no more than 2 lines of text, and having like 6 of those, it would be really ugly to have 6 2-liners on 6 pages instead of 6 2-liners on 1 page (since that would fit on one page).

Comment: What about to establish a threshold of lines (or divs or letters or anything). Keep concatenation what you need to be flushed on pdf. Evertyme the thresold is reached you add a new page.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean with 'tried "avoid page break"'

But the following seems like this worked well for me with latest MPDF:

```
@media print {
    div {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work (well) for floating divs.